# Loop Through all tables in Mysql database and get Average of identical columns from each table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies in advance for the table structure...but I have multiple tables each pertaining to a different user's collected data.
That data is collected continuously and just adds more rows as it happens...
As I've said I have multiple tables with this similar structure and I would like to end up with an average value over 10 groups of 5 colums. (fb1 + fb2 + fb3 + fb4 + fb5)/5 = average for q's 1-5....

The Columns each refer to an answer derived from a web application survey and are all valued from 1-10. These questions are in groups of 5 and are added together then devided by 5 for an average value....

What I want is this, but looping over all of the columns from all of the tables and getting the same result on a grander scale.

I have the formula for this per table as seen below, but how can i loop over an unset number of tables to output the same values taking into account values from multiple tables?

```
    $query="SELECT AVG(fb1), AVG(fb2), AVG(fb3), AVG(fb4), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb6), AVG(fb7), AVG(fb8), AVG(fb9), AVG(fb10), AVG(fb11), AVG(fb12), AVG(fb13), AVG(fb14), AVG(fb15), AVG(fb16), AVG(fb17), AVG(fb18), AVG(fb19), AVG(fb20), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb5), AVG(fb21), AVG(fb22), AVG(fb23), AVG(fb24), AVG(fb25), AVG(fb26), AVG(fb27), AVG(fb28), AVG(fb29), AVG(fb30), AVG(fb31), AVG(fb32), AVG(fb33), AVG(fb34), AVG(fb35), AVG(fb36), AVG(fb37), AVG(fb38), AVG(fb39), AVG(fb40), AVG(fb41), AVG(fb42), AVG(fb43), AVG(fb44), AVG(fb45), AVG(fb46), AVG(fb47), AVG(fb48), AVG(fb49), AVG(fb50) FROM `".$_SESSION['table']."`";

$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$row1 = $row['AVG(fb1)'] + $row['AVG(fb2)'] + $row['AVG(fb3)'] + $row['AVG(fb4)'] +     $row['AVG(fb5)'];
$row2 = $row['AVG(fb6)'] + $row['AVG(fb7)'] + $row['AVG(fb8)'] + $row['AVG(fb9)'] + $row['AVG(fb10)'];
$row3 = $row['AVG(fb11)'] + $row['AVG(fb12)'] + $row['AVG(fb13)'] + $row['AVG(fb14)'] + $row['AVG(fb15)'];
$row4 = $row['AVG(fb16)'] + $row['AVG(fb17)'] + $row['AVG(fb18)'] + $row['AVG(fb19)'] + $row['AVG(fb20)'];
$row5 = $row['AVG(fb20)'] + $row['AVG(fb22)'] + $row['AVG(fb23)'] + $row['AVG(fb24)'] + $row['AVG(fb25)'];
$row6 = $row['AVG(fb26)'] + $row['AVG(fb27)'] + $row['AVG(fb28)'] + $row['AVG(fb29)'] + $row['AVG(fb30)'];
$row7 = $row['AVG(fb30)'] + $row['AVG(fb32)'] + $row['AVG(fb33)'] + $row['AVG(fb34)'] + $row['AVG(fb35)'];
$row8 = $row['AVG(fb36)'] + $row['AVG(fb37)'] + $row['AVG(fb38)'] + $row['AVG(fb39)'] + $row['AVG(fb40)'];
$row9 = $row['AVG(fb40)'] + $row['AVG(fb42)'] + $row['AVG(fb43)'] + $row['AVG(fb44)'] + $row['AVG(fb45)'];
$row10 = $row['AVG(fb46)'] + $row['AVG(fb47)'] + $row['AVG(fb48)'] + $row['AVG(fb49)'] + $row['AVG(fb50)'];

    $row1Avg = $row1 / 5;
    $row2Avg = $row2 / 5;
    $row3Avg = $row3 / 5;
    $row4Avg = $row4 / 5;
    $row5Avg = $row5 / 5;
    $row6Avg = $row6 / 5;
    $row7Avg = $row7 / 5;
    $row8Avg = $row8 / 5;
    $row9Avg = $row9 / 5;
    $row10Avg = $row10 / 5;

echo " all of those";
```

p.s.
As I've done everything without using this PDO syntax everyone is talking about, I would really appreciate any help apart from PDO solutions unless it's not possible.

Comment: How would the multiple tables be named? And how would the tables relate to each other? Would each table have the same structure? (each one with 50 columns named in the same way)

Comment: They are all dynamically created when a new user is added to the database and named accordingly 'johnsmith', 'buddymcguy' etc. a combination of their first and last name. They don't relate to each other directly, apart from being similar in that they're attached under the same user or 'johnsmith'.
Yes They all have the same structure and it involves fb1 - fb50 and several more fields relative to the entry.

Comment: So there are many tables with 1 row each one with that user's data? Or those are the 'creators' and each table has different rows from different users? I don't really understand the concept. Or I do but it doesn't make much sense...

Comment: sorry, ok...
a 'users' table which is also used as a login table,
several 'user' tables that each hold 50 colums of answers of survey questions (and other various information fields)
each row is someone who has filled out a survey under that particular 'user' or 'johnsmith'..

Sorry if this isn't making sense, I can post the structure if I figure out how..

Comment: Alright, that makes much more sense if you have different tables for different surveys. So you want to average the 5 first columns from all the different tables together, right? Is it already designed or are you designing it? Because I have a recommendation for the later to make it much easier.

Comment: I was thinking something like

    $loop = mysql_query("SHOW tables FROM $database")
or die ('cannot select tables');

while($table = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
{
 and then do some query here for each table and get the average then? I am lost...

}

Comment: I put what I have done so far so you can get an idea on how complex it's getting to avoid all the possible bugs (that I'm aware of) and comment on it. It's not perfect, but I think with a little of work it should work. Use that query you just wrote to display all the tables and then input them manually in my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9983/discussion-between-user482024-and-frank-presencia-fandos)

Answer (score 1):

First I will take the freedom to change $row1, $row2... for the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) $group[1], $group[2]... not to confuse them with the actual rows. They are not rows, they are actually groups of columns.

First, the query. I wouldn't do it in that way. You have clearly a progression, so why not to take advantage of this?

```
//First, a couple of definitions.
$group=array();
$default=0;     //If there are no results, the default is 0
$k=0;

// The following query looks like this: SELECT AVG(fb1), [...], AVG(fb50) FROM `table`
$queryA="SELECT ";
for ($i=1; $i<50; $i++)
    $queryA.="AVG(fb".$i."), "
$queryA.="AVG(fb50) FROM `table`";
$resultA=mysql_query($queryA);

//I don't know all the other table's names, so I assume table2, table3 etc.
//EDIT THIS. Add the code in brackets as many times as tables (with the respective names $queryC, $queryD... and the $resultC, $resultD...):
{
$queryB="SELECT ";
for ($i=1; $i<50; $i++)
    $queryB.="AVG(fb".$i."), "
$queryB.="AVG(fb50) FROM `table2'`";
$resultB=mysql_query($queryB);
}

$num=0;
//EDIT THIS. Add as many as needed. Gets which result is longer.
if (mysql_num_rows($resultA)>=$num)
    $num=mysql_num_rows($resultA);
if (mysql_num_rows($resultB)>=$num)
    $num=mysql_num_rows($resultB);

//Then, the while loop:
for($a=0; $a<$num; $a++)
    {
    //EDIT THIS. Add as many as needed
    $rowA = mysql_fetch_array($resultA)
    $rowB = mysql_fetch_array($resultB);

    // Repeat it 50 times
    for ($j=0; j<50;j++)
        {
        //EDIT THIS. Add as many as tables suming up.
        $group[$k]+=$rowA["AVG(fb".$j.")"]+$rowB["AVG(fb".$j.")"];

        //EDIT THIS. Get the number to divide for the average
        if (!empty($rowA["AVG(fb".$j.")"])) $group["n".$k]+=1;
        if (!empty($rowB["AVG(fb".$j.")"])) $group["n".$k]+=1;

        //Checks if $j is 4, 9, 14, 19 etc (groups of 5 as 0 is included)
        if ($j%5==4)
            {
            $k++;
            }
    }

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
$group=(float) $group[$i]
$div=(float) $group["n".$i];
if ($div!=0)
    {
    $group[$i]=$group/$div;
    }
else $group[$i]=$default;
echo "<br>Group ".$i.": ".$group[$i];
}
```

As you can see, **it won't work with copy/paste**. I assume that you enter manually all data in few different places. ONLY edit the lines just below where the comments say **'EDIT THIS'**. The rest of comments are explanations and require no further work. I haven't tested it but I believe it'll work if you input manually all the tablenames and require fields I detailed.

Thought I have to tell you, this is not a 'good' practice. It'd be much better to put all the data in one table `values` adding a field called `creator_id` and to create another table called `creators` with the same `creator_id` field and a `name` field. Then you use `WHERE creator_id=$whatever` for seeing individual surveys.